# Optimizing (Compressing) GIF images in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gif, file-size, optimization

I am trying to optimize an animated GIF image in Photoshop. The current size is 2.2 MB. Following the guides I found online, they told me to *"Save as Web"* and then decrease the colors from 256 down to 128 or 64.

I tried that — however, when I try to decrease it, the size actually increased.

- 128 colors = 4.4 MB
- 64 colors = 5 MB

Does anyone know why this is happening?

### Original (256 colors):

[image: 256]

### After (128 colors):

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your settings or describe them? It isn't normal behavior with defaults.

Comment: Sure, this is the original image: http://i.imgur.com/EhxvLb2.png

This is the image after changing color to 128: http://i.imgur.com/lz9UyGZ.png

Comment: I have also tried to turn off diffuse but it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: One thing I notice-- and I don't know what it means, is that the image on the top is different from the image on the bottom slightly.

Comment: He's just painting out the image for privacy. Caught my eye at first too: "where are all those colors being used?" ;)

Comment: Try it on another installation of PS. Something's wrong with the app.

Comment: We can't say exactly why without seeing the image, but it's likely to a change in a) dithering = GIFs compress by grouping like pixels in each horizontal row. Dithering breaks that up and b) colors changing from frame to frame. Fewer colors may equal more of the pixels change between frames.

Comment: You also may want to look into CSS animations, depending on the type of animation you are after.

Answer (score 8):

Fewer colors + 100% dither + no Transparency Dither = greater size.

Adding a transparency dither or reducing the color dithering to less than 100% will most likely reduce the file size.

When you reduce the color table and have a high dither setting, you ask Photoshop to dither with fewer colors. This actually creates *more* color data to maintain from frame to frame, thus increasing the file size. The fact that your animation has 157 frames with 100% dithering it wouldn't surprise me if the file size quadrupled due to the dithering setting.

If you are truly interested in reducing the file size, you need to prune at least half those frames. This is especially true if image changes between the frames are present for all 157 frames. You simply can't squeeze a blue whale into a tuna can.

Comment: I just want to reduce it to below 2 mb so that I can upload it online. I tried to reduce the dithering to 0, and set a transparency dither but the size decreased by like 0.05 mb. I guess I'll take a look at reducing the number of frames.

Comment: 0% dithering can increase file size the same as 100% dithering can. Try odd percentages.. 43%, 64%, etc. Another option is to try the "Optimize to file size" in the Save for web window preferences. Then see what gets changed when you allow Save for Web to optimize the image.

Comment: Dithering, itself, sounds like a problem. Gotta watch out for people who dither around.

Comment: 2 megabytes is still a fat animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, use either dither or color table reduction, but not both.

I recommend you use the Lossy slider. You have it set at zero. You can crank it up. The higher you go, the more information Photoshop will throw away as it converts your image into a GIF, and the smaller the file size will get.